# I want to download ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

I can't wait to download ubuntu 14.04. When wil it be able to download? And will I be able to turn on wifi and bluetooth? please answer

Comment: see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule wifi & bluetooth is -as always, available

Answer (score 0):

you can already download it [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/), but it is still in development, en I would not suggest to install it on your daily machine. The final release will be on April 17th (see comment Jacob).

If you have problems with your bluethooth and wifi, look on this site if someone else asked the question, or ask a new question to try to solve it. Make sure to include as much technical information as possible about your machine and the wireless chip.